# How to download files using axios.post in React using webapi Core

Tags: reactjs, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

I have used this [How to download files using axios.post from webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949640/how-to-download-files-using-axios-post-from-webapi) (It could be duplicate of this) to work on this scenario but i am not getting success.

```
 React: 
   axios.post("URL",{data:data, responseType: "blob"})
```

1. In response i am getting corrupted data, not bytes.
2. ResponseType works with get request but why not with post?

`WebAPI Core:
  return File(arraybytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
  officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "test.xlsx");`

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I could be able to download videos that are hosted on S3 AWS buckets,

```
const handleDownload = () => {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.target = "_blank";
    link.download = "YOUR_FILE_NAME"
    axios
      .get(url, {
        responseType: "blob",
      })
      .then((res) => {
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(
          new Blob([res.data], { type: "video/mp4" })
        );
        link.click();
      });
  };
```

And I trigger **handleDownload** function in a button with **onClick**.

The **url** in the function has the video URL from S3 buckets