# How to download a file through an API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

In my react app, I have a component which has a file download button for download a file coming from the Back end. I'm using `AXIOS` for the `AJAX` call. **The problem is, after downloading the file, it is corrupted. I'm downloading `png` files and `pdf` files. When I open the downloaded image, it says it's corrupted and downloaded `pdf` shows white background only.** How can I download a file correctly?

** Component:**

```js
import API from "../../api/api";

class DocumentsTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fileId: 4
    };
    this.downloadMapById = this.downloadMapById.bind(this);
  }

  downloadMapById() {
    const type = 1;
    const file_id = this.state.fileId;

    const FileDownload = require("js-file-download");

    API.post("project/files/download", { file_id, type })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        FileDownload(data, "myImage.png");
        console.log("success!", data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={() => this.downloadMapById}>Download</button>;
  }
}
```

**API file:**

```js
import axios from "axios";

const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL}/api/v1/`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json"
  }
});
```

Comment: You should download the file as binary not json

Comment: @Dominic So should I set the Content type as binary or Octet stream?

Comment: Correct - "The recommended action for an implementation that receives an
"application/octet-stream" entity is to simply offer to put the data in a file"

Comment: See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49040247/download-binary-file-with-axios remember to add `responseType: 'arraybuffer',` and I think you can change Accept to a generic octet stream

Comment: @Dominic Thank you! That answer solved my problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As I am not able to add comments so posting as answer.
I have tried the same thing and posted the question for same in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901499/how-to-download-files-using-axios-post-in-react-using-webapi-core).

For **post** method i get the success with **fetch** as below.

```
 fetch("url",
        { 
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json",'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage["Access_Token"]},
            body:data
        }).then(response => response.blob()).then(response => ...*your code for download*... )
```

You are getting corrupted file because you are not receiving content as **blob** or **arraybuffer**.