# Downloading ByteArray(application/pdf or application/octect-stream) response using react js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, filesaver.js

I'm using springboot backend api to download a pdf file with react frontend. When the backend api is tested on postman, it asks to download the response, and the expected pdf gets downloaded. When I integrate the api with react, it shows the following in the response,

> %PDF-1.4
>   %����
>   2 0 obj
>   <>stream
>   x����n�0��~
>   �Ò�M����ay�I��P��ɲk���Kٰb�d�"?�����v�N��p������N�o: ��O��ӏ��z:��D
>   &����#����"�[�Gпr��
>   r�[��ƽ�EM ���ać�����E�Pw��3Dn1�ض���"qr����2�B   �Rz���E�ɕl�b6�?H`��T搵�DS��;�Zh�&�ƅ�J.s*i���H��fX�ʪ��6�(��x=w߻��
>   endstream
>   endobj
>   4 0 obj
>   <>>>/Contents 2 0 R/Parent 3 0 R>>
>   endobj
>   1 0 obj
>   <>
>   endobj
>   3 0 obj
>   <>
>   endobj
>   5 0 obj
>   <>
>   endobj
>   6 0 obj
>   <>
>   endobj
>   xref
>   0 7
>   0000000000 65535 f 
>   0000000590 00000 n 
>   0000000015 00000 n 
>   0000000676 00000 n 
>   0000000478 00000 n 
>   0000000727 00000 n 
>   0000000772 00000 n 
>   trailer
>   <<2324328368ff9e8a10923bbe7a3d048d>]>>
>   %iText-5.5.13.1
>   startxref
>   1020
>   %%EOF

but never gets downloaded. So I found these solutions, which require the response type='blob'
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47079123/10598769 -This solution downloads me only a blank pdf.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41940307/10598769 -Downloads a blank pdf as well

[image]

However, if I try on postman as said earlier, the pdf downloaded is not blank.

Please help me with a workaround for this. Any help is appriciated.

Front end code;
From service class-i've used 'file-saver' here. but I've tried other options here the same way.

```
const downloadarticle=createLogic({
    type:downloadArticleTypes.DOWNLOAD_ARTICLE,
    latest:true,
    debounce:1000,

    process({
        action
    },dispatch,done){
        let HTTPclient=api

        // debugger
        console.log("payload check",action.payload)

        let obj={
            generatedText:action.payload.generated_text,
        }

        HTTPclient.postPDF(endPoints.DOWNLOAD_ARTICLE+"/"+action.payload.article_id,obj)
            .then(resp=> {
                // debugger
                console.log(resp.data)

                var blob = new Blob([resp.data], {type: "application/pdf"});
                saveAs(blob, resp.data.filename)

            })
            .catch(err=>{
                var errormsg="Failed to download Article";
                if (err && err.code === "ECONNABORTED") {
                    errormsg = "Please check your internet connection.";
                }
                dispatch(downloadArticleActions.DdownloadArticleFail(errormsg))
            }).then(()=>done());
    }
})
```

HttpClient class code for the post

```
export const postPDF=(route,imgdata,responseType='blob')=>{
    instance || setAuth()
    return instance.post(route,imgdata,responseType)
    // dtodata == null ? { dtodata: {} } : dtodata= JSON.stringify(dtodata),
}
```

on the component, I call the action, on Download button click as follows

```
 onDownloadClick=()=>{
        let obj={
            article_id:0,
            generated_text:this.state.item.caption
        }

        this.props.downloadArticleActions.downloadArticle(obj)
    }
```

Backend API implementation;
**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> downloadArticle(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String token, @PathVariable("id") long id,@RequestBody MaskedLMDTO dto) throws DocumentException {

        Article article=articleService.downloadPDF(id,dto);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
        headers.add("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + article.getDateTime() + ".pdf");
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData( article.getDateTime()+ ".pdf", article.getDateTime() + ".pdf");

        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(article.getArticleFile(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, could you post the code that you are using on the frontend side please?

Comment: @Terry, sure. I've added it as an edit above.

Comment: Thanks, can you try to add the following to your HTTP headers before making the POST call : {headers: {'Accept': 'application/pdf'}} ?

Comment: @Terry, in frontend yeah?

Comment: @Terry, I tried. Same, no luck.

Comment: @DilrukshiPerera, Were you able to Solve the Issue? Even I'm facing similar issue

Answer (score 1):

Can you try calling your server using fetch method and download the PDF using `downloadjs` available here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs?

I guess your code will then look something like:

```html
fetch(endPoints.DOWNLOAD_ARTICLE+"/"+action.payload.article_id, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: obj,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
}).then(function(resp) {
  filename = resp.data.filename;
  return resp.blob();
}).then(function(blob) {
  return download(blob, filename);
});
```